# How do I upload files to a graphql backend implemented using graphql-upload using axios?

Tags: express, graphql, axios

I have a GraphQL backend implemented using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express), [express-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-graphql), [graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql) and [graphql-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-upload). My GraphQL schema declaration is as follows:

```
type OProject {
    _id: ID!
    title: String!
    theme: String!
    budget: Float!
    documentation: String!
    date: Date
}

input IProject {
    title: String!
    theme: String!
    budget: Float!
    file: Upload!
}

type Mutations {
    create(data: IProject): OProject
}

type Mutation {
    Project: Mutations
}
```

I want to make a `create` request to my GraphQL API  at */graphql* using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). How go I go about it?

Answer (score 10):

Following the GraphQL multipart request specification [detailed here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) you would go about doing so by:

- creating a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) instance and populating it with the following:

  - The `operations` field,
  - the `map` field and,
  - the files to upload

**Creating the FormData Instance**

```js
var formData = new FormData();
```

**The `operations` field:**

The value of this field will be a JSON string containing the GraphQL `query` and `variables`. You must set all file field in the `variables` object to null e.g:

```js
const query = `
    mutation($project: IProject!) {
        Project { create(data: $project) { _id } }
    }
`;

const project = {
    title: document.getElementById("project-title").value,
    theme: document.getElementById("project-theme").value,
    budget: Number(document.getElementById("project-budget").value),
    file: null
};

const operations = JSON.stringify({ query, variables: { project } });
formData.append("operations", operations);
```

**The `map` field:**

As its name implies, the value of this field will be a JSON string of an object whose keys are the names of the field in the FormData instance containing the files. The value of each field will be an array containing a string indicating to which field in the `variables` object the file, corresponding to value's key, will be bound to  e.g:

```
const map = {
    "0": ["variables.project.file"]
};
formData.append("map", JSON.stringify(map));
```

**The files to upload**
You then should add the files to the FormData instance as per the `map`. In this case;

```js
const file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
formData.append("0", file);
```

And that is it. You are now ready to make the request to your backend using axios and the FormData instance:

```js
axios({
    url: "/graphql",
    method: "post",
    data: formData
})
    .then(response => { ... })
    .catch(error => { ... });
```

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to send the input as a list of objects of type project. The input must be file for each entry in the list so I can't manage to link multiple files, one for each project. Any idea how it could be achieved?

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps you could provide a code snippet showing the object you want to send.

Comment: i am trying to upload multiple files

Comment: I am trying to use you comment but i couldn't do it he is keeping telling me that the $file inside my query is not defined ex: `DocumentUpload(payload: { file: $file })`
`JSON.stringify({ query, variables: { file: null } })`
`formData.append("operations", operations);`

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of @Archy

If you are using definition of what you expect in GraphQl like `Inputs` don't forget to set your graphql mutation definition after the mutation keyword

You have to put the definition of your payload like this

```js
const query = `
mutation MutationName($payload: Input!) {
  DocumentUpload(payload: $payload) {
    someDataToGet
  }
}`
```

And your operations like this the `operationName` and the order doesn't matter

```js
const operations = JSON.stringify({ operationName: "MutationName", variables: { payload: { file: null } }, query })
```