# How to upload images to fastify + graphql backend with axios?

Tags: node.js, graphql, axios, apollo-server, fastify

When sending images via axios I found I have to use formdata. I add my images here but when sending the formdata my entire backend just freezes, just says "pending".

Ive been following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59043021/how-do-i-upload-files-to-a-graphql-backend-implemented-using-graphql-upload-usin)

And my attempt so far:

backend:

Apollo:

```
import { ApolloServer, makeExecutableSchema } from 'apollo-server-fastify';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  uploads: {
    maxFileSize: 10000000,
    maxFiles: 5,
  },
});

(async function() {
  app.register(apolloServer.createHandler({ path: '/api' }));
})();
```

schema:

```
  scalar DateTime
  scalar Upload

  input addUser {
    Email: String!
    Password: String
    FirstName: String!
    LastName: String!
    Age: DateTime!
    JobTitle: String!
    File: Upload
  }

  type Mutation {
    register(input: addUser!): Boolean
  }
```

resolver:

```
  Mutation: {
    register: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
        // how to get the formData?
      },
  }
```

FrontEnd:

I build the request like this:

```
const getMutation = (mutate: MutationNames, returParams?: any): any => {
  const mutation = {
    login: print(
      gql`
        mutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
          login(email: $email, password: $password) {
            token
            refreshToken
          }
        }
      `
    ),
    register: print(
      gql`
        mutation(
          $firstName: String!
          $email: String!
          $lastName: String!
          $age: DateTime!
          $jobTitle: String!
          $file: Upload
        ) {
          register(
            input: {
              FirstName: $firstName
              LastName: $lastName
              Email: $email
              Age: $age
              JobTitle: $jobTitle
              File: $file
            }
          )
        }
      `
    ),

  }[mutate];

  if (!mutation) return {};

  return mutation;
};
```

In this case im using the register mutation.

I have a few hooks on how I handle the data fetching so Im not going to include it since it is alot of code. The data is fetched correctly in the front end and before posting to the backend im putting everything to a formData object:

```
  const submitForm: SubmitForm = (obj: SendObject) => {
    const Fdata = new FormData();

    Fdata.append('0', fileImp.file);

    Fdata.append('operations', JSON.stringify(obj.data));

    const map = {
      '0': ['variables.file'],
    };
    Fdata.append('map', JSON.stringify(map));

    callAxiosFn(
      {
        method,
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
        data: Fdata,
        // headers: obj.headers,
      },
      qlType.toString()
    );
  };
```

gets called like this:

```
  const response = await axios({
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'x-token': localStorage.getItem('token'),
      'x-refresh-token': localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'),
      ...(config.headers || {}),
    },
    ...config,
  });
```

config is `AxiosRequestConfig`

What Im sending:

[image]

I dont exactly understand How the formdata will hit my resolver endpoint  and for that reason im doing something wrong since the backend returns:

> (node:748) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: [object Array] (node:748)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:748) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I realize this is alot but Im at the end of my vits here, been at this the entire day. Any help is deeply appreciated.

EDIT:

Since my backend was questioned I thought I would just show that when sending data without appending Formdata like I do above then I get it working:

```
  const submitForm: SubmitForm = (obj: SendObject) => {

    callAxiosFn(
      {
        method,
        url: 'http://localhost:4000/api',
        data: obj.data,
      },
      qlType.toString()
    );
  };
```

obj.data is:

```
{query: "mutation ($firstName: String!, $email: String!, $l… Age: $age, JobTitle: $jobTitle, File: $file})↵}↵", variables: {…}}
query: "mutation ($firstName: String!, $email: String!, $lastName: String!, $age: DateTime!, $jobTitle: String!, $file: Upload) {↵  register(input: {FirstName: $firstName, LastName: $lastName, Email: $email, Age: $age, JobTitle: $jobTitle, File: $file})↵}↵"
variables:
age: "1977-04-04"
email: "JhoneDoe@hotmail.com"
file: File {name: "something.jpg", lastModified: 1589557760497, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 15 2020 17:49:20 GMT+0200 (centraleuropeisk sommartid), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 32355, …}
firstName: "Jhon"
jobTitle: "SomethingCool"
lastName: "Doe"
password: "CoolPassword!"123"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

query getting sent in the browser:

[image]

Backend reciving the data but the image is not included:
[image]

EDIT:

Recently found that my fastify backend might have issues with reading formData.
tried installing

```
fastify-multipart
```

but got errors when registering it:

> FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT(contentType) ^ FastifyError
>   [FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT]:

After that I tried:

```
npm uninstall fastify-file-upload
```

Error remained.

Comment: bad mutation syntax - no return content def - you have to return something - at least some `{ id }`

Comment: `file` not `null`-ed

Comment: `Fdata.append('file'...` - why not "0"?  .... IMHO you should separate problems ... get working client recipe (1st link) and make backend working ... then recreate it with needed customizations ... too many changes at once

Comment: Updated the question to show a fully functioning backend when im not sending the data as formData. Problem is then that Im not hitting the resolver and also file is not included.

Comment: `mutation name( input ) { result }` - you have **no result part** in your query (I don't care about code)..... start with **workimg formData (FE) example** and proof that BE is working ... then adapt FE to your needs

Comment: The result here is less important for the time being. I will be returning a bolean if everything goes right BUT im not hitting the resolver at all. Just getting a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. Starting to think that my fastify-server does not know how to handle formData

Comment: HMMM, don't you think **you should mention it earlier**? formData probably supported, multipart probably not (https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/1596), uploading in graphql needs additional customization, too - server must know what to do with `operations`

Comment: If I had know that it was an issue I would have mentioned it. Ive read through that issue and got FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT(contentType) ^ FastifyError [FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT]. tried unisnatlling  npm uninstall fastify-file-upload but the error remained.

Comment: Tried that lib and got the same aswell: FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT(contentType) ^ FastifyError [FST_ERR_CTP_ALREADY_PRESENT] A content parser is there. something else is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took some time and usally when you take something for granted it takes time to find the mistake.

For anyone having the same problem please remember that the order you add something MATTERS!

What I did:

```
const Fdata = new FormData();

Fdata.append('0', fileImp.file);  // NOTICE THIS

Fdata.append('operations', JSON.stringify(obj.data));

const map = { // NOTICE THIS
  '0': ['variables.file'],
};
Fdata.append('map', JSON.stringify(map));
```

Problem: 
Remember when I said order of appending things matter? Well the case here was that the mapping was added after the file was added.

The correct way:

```
const Fdata = new FormData();

Fdata.append('operations', JSON.stringify(obj.data));

const map = { // NOTICE THIS
  '0': ['variables.file'],
};
Fdata.append('map', JSON.stringify(map));
Fdata.append('0', fileImp.file);  // NOTICE THIS
```

Also note that in my qestion I missed setting the file itself to null in the variables:

```
  variables: {
    file: null,
  },
```

This has to be done.

For more info [read here](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec)

Comment: congrats, you could have this working a few days earlier ... just by more strictly following guide you followed :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have not explored this topic yet. But I know that **axios** with **GraphQL** does not really work that well. Axios is made mainly for **REST API** calls. However, I really like and have learned a lot from this channel [Ben Awad](https://www.youtube.com/user/99baddawg). The guy is really awesome and explains things clearly and nice. But the most important he is a GraphQL enthusiast and explores and presents various topic about it, as well with **React.js**, **TypeORM** & **PostgreSQL**. Here are some helpful links, from his channel, that might help with your issue:

- [Upload Files in GraphQL Using Apollo Upload](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V95tULgGpLo&t=314s)
- [How to Upload a File to Apollo Server in React](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Zx-9BKgTAs)

I hope this helps! Please let me know if the content is helpful!

Comment: Very usefull links and I also follow Ben's videos! I have implemneted everything with axios and it has worked perfectly with the exception now when trying to send over file data.

Comment: I am really happy to hear that! Always nice to help people. Please, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer too.

Comment: I appreciate the links and think it is usefull but it is not the answer to my question. I refuse to accept that this can not be done, Im messing up somewhere.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your honest answer too. At least I hope I helped just a little with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

@CodingLittle glad you figured out [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895554/1596978) was related to the multipart form field ordering.

Some things to add (answering as I don't have the 50 reputation required to make a comment on your answer, despite being the [`graphql-upload`](https://npm.im/graphql-upload) author)…

> Also note that in my qestion I missed setting the file itself to null in the variables

This is true, and good to get right, although in reality a lot of [GraphQL multipart request spec](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) server implementations will simply replace whatever is at the mapped path for a file with the upload scalar value without caring what was there — in theory, you could replace files in variables with `asdf` instead of `null` and it would still work. `JSON.stringify` would have replaced the file instances with something like `{}`.

A lot of your headaches could have been avoided if the backend responded with a clear 400 status and descriptive error message instead of throwing a gnarly `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error. If your [`graphql-upload`](https://npm.im/graphql-upload) dependency was up to date on the backend, you should have seen a descriptive error message when the requests were not conforming to the [GraphQL multipart request spec](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) regarding [field ordering](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec#multipart-form-field-structure), as can be seen in the [`graphql-upload`](https://npm.im/graphql-upload) tests:

https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/blob/v11.0.0/test/public/processRequest.test.js#L929

Try running `npm ls graphql-upload` in your backend project to check only one version is installed, and that it’s the latest published to npm (v11 at the time of this answer). Note that if you’re relying on Apollo Server to install it for you, they use a very out of date version (v8).