# How can I write a multipart (data and files) GraphQL request in axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, graphql

I use an GraphQL API with Django (graphene-django) and I need to upload files through this API.

The Backend mutation is as following (I use the graphene-file-upload library):

```
class UploadBOM(graphene.relay.ClientIDMutation, ProjectMixin):

    class Input:
        bom = Upload()
        project_id = graphene.ID(required=True)
        region = graphene.String(required=True)
        is_test = graphene.Boolean()

    @project_authorization
    def mutate_and_get_payload(root, info, **inputs):
        is_test = inputs.get('is_test', False)
        inputs['project'].upload_bom(
            inputs['bom'], 
            inputs['region'], 
            is_test
        )
        return UploadBOM(project=inputs['project'])
```

*@project_authorization decorator is used for checking if the user can modify the project model.*

I have already made the query work with curl and inside Insomnia, but I'm going nuts with VueJs (axios).

This is how it works with curl.

```
curl http://localhost:8001/graphql \
  -F operations='{"query": "mutation ($file: Upload, $projectId: ID!, $region: String!, $isTest: Boolean) { uploadBom(input: {bom: $file, projectId: $projectId, region: $region, isTest: $isTest }) { project {id} }}", "variables": { "file": null, "projectId": "THE_PROJECT_ID", "region": "Lombardia", "isTest": true}}' \
  -F map='{ "0": ["variables.file"]}' \
  -F 0=@CME4.xlsx \
  -H "Authorization: JWT MYJSONTOKEN"
```

I have searched stack overflow for an answer and tried the following with no luck:

```
async previewFile(event) {
      const bomFile = event.target.files[0]
      alert(bomFile)
      const formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('operations', {"query": "mutation ($file: Upload, $projectId: ID!, $region: String!, $isTest: Boolean) { uploadBom(input: {bom: $file, projectId: $projectId, region: $region, isTest: $isTest }) { project {id} }}", "variables": { "file": bomFile, "projectId": "UHJvamVjdE5vZGU6MTU=", "region": "Lombardia", "isTest": true}})
      formData.append('0', bomFile)
      formData.append('map', { '0': ["variables.file"]})
      
      try {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
          "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("edilgo-token")
        const result = await axios({
          method: 'POST',
          url: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
          data: formData,
        })
        alert(result)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    },
```

And also this:

```
methods: {
    async previewFile(event) {
      const bomFile = event.target.files[0]
      alert(bomFile)
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] =
        "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("edilgo-token")
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/graphql"
      axios.defaults.headers.common["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "multipart/form-data"
      const isTest = true // GIL: some condition that nows when it's the real deal
      const result = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
        data: {
          query: `
              mutation (
                $file: Upload,
                $projectId: ID!,
                $region: String!,
                $isTest: Boolean,
              ) {
              uploadBom(
                input: {
                  bom: $file,
                  projectId: $projectId,
                  region: $region,
                  isTest: $isTest,
                }) {
                    project {
                        id
                        name
                      }
                  }
              }
            `,
          variables: {
            file: bomFile,
            projectId: "UHJvamVjdE5vZGU6MTU=",
            region: "Lombardia",
            isTest: isTest
          }
        }
      })
      console.log(result.data.data.projects)
    }
  }
```

Client side is giving me the error following:

```
BOMUpload.vue?2363:79 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:15)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

The error traceback I get from Django is:

```
2020-10-08 14:07:54,394 - ERROR - Internal Server Error: /graphql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene_django/views.py", line 151, in dispatch
    data = self.parse_body(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene_file_upload/django/__init__.py", line 15, in parse_body
    operations = json.loads(request.POST.get('operations', '{}'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi xadm. I already have, with no good results. It would help a lot if you linked me the answer :-)

Comment: f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895554/6124657 ... if you know what is expected in request (curl example) then explore browser devtools/network request headers and body detaily

Comment: Thanks xadm! I found the solution in the link you send me. I needed to invert the order of appending form data (formData.append('map', { '0': ["variables.file"]}) before appending the file) and also use JSON.stringify to encode the formData