# React redux upload image with graphql and use of axios

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, axios, graphql

***When I try to upload image i getting an error:***

```
 xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:3000/graphql 400 (Bad Request)
 categoryAction.tsx:57 Error: Request failed with status code 400
 at createError (createError.js:16)
 at settle (settle.js:17)
 at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

**When I upload From the postman upload successfuly but when try with react axios getting above error**

**My Form**

```
const addForm = (props:any) => {        
 const [category,setCategory] = useState({
    image:''
 })

  const onDataChange = (e:any,name:string,image:string) => {
    let oldData : any = { ...category }
        const imageFile = e.target.files[0];
        oldData[image] = imageFile;
        setCategory(oldData);
    }

  const onFinish = async (values : any) => {
    let categoryData = {...category}
    let formdata = new FormData();
    
    formdata.append('image',categoryData.image);
    
    await props.AddCategory(formdata);
    console.log('Success:', values);
};


        return (
            <>
               <Form>
               <Form.Item
                    name="image"
                    label="Category Image"
                >
                <Input type="file" name="image" onChange={(e) => onDataChange(e,'image','image')} />
                </Form.Item>
                 <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={onFinish}> Submit </Button>
                </Form>
            </>
}

   const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch:any) => {
     return {
       AddCategory:(data:any) => dispatch(AddCategory(data))
   }
    

  export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(addForm);
```

Now this is my Redux Action

```
export const AddCategory : any = (data:any) => {
return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type:types.INIT_ADD_DATA
    })

    await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/graphql`,
    {  
         query: ` mutation {
            addCategory(image: ${data}){
            imagePath
          }
          }
    `          
    })
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
            type:types.ADD_DATA_SUCCESS,
            myData: { data : response.data}
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        dispatch({
            type:types.ADD_DATA_FAILED,
            error:error.message
        });
    })
  };
};
```

***My API IN Node Is***

```
import { gql }  from 'apollo-server'

const CategoriesTypeDef = gql`
    extend type Mutation {
       addCategory(image: Upload!): Category!
}

type Category {
    categoryId: ID!
    image: String!
}

`
```

while api through post data , data uploaded successfully but use of react typescript axios it will generate error how to fix it .

Comment: template literals are not for files, use query from postman, pass variable properly

Comment: I used same query that use in postman still get same Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: use search ... f.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043022/6124657